# Electron App is not running after being packaged

Tags: node.js, electron, electron-builder, electron-packager

I tried packaging a simple ElectronJS app i created using **electron-builder** and **electron-packager** which resulted in a file that is not runnable. when i click on the icon of the app, nothing happens, no errors and no running.

App is running fine locally and shows a notificaiton when starting as well as a tray icon.

Here is the full code if anyone wants to have a look:

https://github.com/ali-h2010/Electron-Huawei-Router-Unoffical-Utility

Note that i was able to package other sample apps so the issue most likely in my project only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check my comments about why your app is not working even the app has been packaged correctly.

```
  // This is wrong
  // win.loadFile('Views/index.html')
  // This will be aboluste path after packaging the app.
  // So the app will look from the root directory.
  // Not inside the app.

  win.loadFile(path.join(__dirname, 'Views/index.html'))

  win.on('close', function (event) {
    // event.preventDefault();
    // win.hide();
  })

  win.on('minimize', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    win.hide()
  })


  let AppTray = null;

  // Same error
  // const iconPath = 'Assets/Images/BatteryIcons/UnknownBattery.png')
  // AppTray = new Tray(iconPath);
  // After packaging the app there won't be assets on root directory
  const iconPath = path.join(__dirname, 'Assets/Images/BatteryIcons')
  AppTray = new Tray(path.join(iconPath, 'UnknownBattery.png'));
  ...
```

I've made full code on your repo and made PR.

Comment: Before packaging. Electron is executed from node_modules where it is in your app directory. So the basic dir will be your application dir. But after packaging the OS will run your app so basic dir is diff.

Comment: I read your comments and understood why is this happening. Although, it's very tricky to figure this out as the app is working fine without packaging.

Comment: I'm not sure you understood my above comment. But let me hint you one. '__dirname' is an absolute path where your process is running. So this will be working both in dev mode or prod mode